# How automatic website builders handle domain redirections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect

I'm wondering how website builders like wix etc handle domains.
They give the possibility to their customers to register a domain like `www.example.com` to point to the hosted website (generated).

My understanding is that somehow they get the domain (through DNS, but most probably not only) point to their server and redirect to the hosted website (so `www.example.com` loads `www.builder.website/customer/whatever`.

Has anyone build something like this who could share a bit of knowledge ? I'm having trouble finding info about this. I'm trying to achieve a similar thing and we use AWS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Wix before but I used GoDaddy and I imagine they would be similar.

When you purchase a domain, they add your domain `www.example.com` to their Domain Name Server. They let you modify the records (ex: A, CNAME, ...) through their user portal.

So they are not doing any redirection but simply setting up your website using their own DNS.

If you want to purchase a domain from one of these websites and handle everything else on AWS, you simply need to create a Route53 entry in AWS and update the DNS server setting on Wix (or any other provider) to point to the Route53 Hosted Zone name servers.

Comment: Thanks, the question is not really about hosting, I understand that part. The question is about website builders (like wix or any other), hosted somewhere, having another domain pointing somehow to a subfolder (my explanation doesn't make any sense as DNS are for domain to IP only) but I don't know how that works, hence my question.

Comment: If you're asking how a request to Domain A can get redirected to Domain B, then that is done using CNAME records (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)

Comment: no, I'm asking a a request to Domain A can get redirect to Domain B complete path (subfolders included)

Comment: That's what CNAME does. If you redirect example.com to example2.com, all requests to example.com (ex: example.com/customer/whatever) will be redirected to example2.com (ex: example2.com/customer/whatever)

Comment: Thanks. What if I need: `example1.com` to redirect to `example2.com/customer/whatever` ? Can CNAME do this ? (that's where I can't wrap my head around the configuration)

Comment: That can't be done with DNS. You need to setup a server to do that redirect.